# Moving a div on the left, other on right of one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this scrollable tabs using jquery. It's working fine but the only problem i am facing is the position of the two arrow divs. They both are `float:left` but somehow coming stacked together on the right of the main tab container. Both of these divs are being created on run time. My desired positions of these two arrow divs is: left arrow div on the start (before tabs) and the right arrow div on the end (after tabs). Any help or suggestion will be welcomed.

JQuery code is below but to see it working, go here:  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bua2d/210/)

```
(function ($) {
        var settings = {
            barheight: 38
        }
        $.fn.scrollabletab = function (options) {
            var ops = $.extend(settings, options);
            var ul = this.children('ul').first();
            var ulHtmlOld = ul.html();
            var tabBarWidth = $(this).width() - 60;
            ul.wrapInner('<div class="fixedContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: ' + tabBarWidth + 'px; overflow: hidden; float: left;"><div class="moveableContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: 5000px; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div></div>');
            ul.append('<div style="width: 20px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
            var leftArrow = ul.children().last();
            leftArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w" } });
            leftArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-w').first().css('left', '2px');
            ul.append('<div style="width: 20px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
            var rightArrow = ul.children().last();
            rightArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e" } });
            rightArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-e').first().css('left', '2px');
            var moveable = ul.find('.moveableContainer').first();
            leftArrow.click(function () {
                var offset = tabBarWidth / 6;
                var currentPosition = moveable.css('left').replace('px', '') / 1;
                if (currentPosition + offset >= 0) {
                    moveable.stop().animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow');
                }
                else {
                    moveable.stop().animate({ left: currentPosition + offset + 'px' }, 'slow');
                }
            });
            rightArrow.click(function () {
                var offset = tabBarWidth / 6;
                var currentPosition = moveable.css('left').replace('px', '') / 1;
                var tabsRealWidth = 0;
                ul.find('li').each(function (index, element) {
                    tabsRealWidth += $(element).width();
                    tabsRealWidth += ($(element).css('margin-right').replace('px', '') / 1);
                });
                tabsRealWidth *= -1;
                if (currentPosition - tabBarWidth > tabsRealWidth) {
                    moveable.stop().animate({ left: currentPosition - offset + 'px' }, 'slow');
                }
            });
            return this;
        }; // end of functions
    })(jQuery);
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs().scrollabletab();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your arrows both appear on the right of your `fixedContainer`, is because your `fixedContainer` is floated to the left as well.

If you have multiple elements with `float: left;`, they will be stacked next to eachother in the order of which they appear. Your HTML is rendered like this:

```
<div class="fixedContainer"></div>   <!-- your menu tabs -->
<div role="button"></div>            <!-- your left arrow -->
<div role="button"></div>            <!-- your right arrow -->
```

And all 3 of these divs are floated to the left, so they will appear next to eachother.

If you want your left arrow to appear to the left of your menu tabs, you will need to re-arrange your structure like this:

```
<div role="button"></div>            <!-- your left arrow -->
<div class="fixedContainer"></div>   <!-- your menu tabs -->
<div role="button"></div>            <!-- your right arrow -->
```

To do this, you need to change your Javascript code for the left arrow as following:

```
ul.prepend('<div style="width: 20px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
var leftArrow = ul.children().first();
```

This will [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the arrow instead of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), so it appears before the `fixedContainer`.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bua2d/211/)

Comment: Sounds right.. I get your point but it seems to be impossible for me to merge this piece of code with the existing jquery-ui.js in the way you described. Currently i just pasted this piece of code at the end and it gave that behavior.. but not sure where and how to place them in the middle.. whatever i try, the whole placement and CSS seems to get dismantled.. Can you please look into that..

Comment: @AbdulJabbar I have edited my answer and added how you can change your Javascript code for this to work. However, you should really try and understand the code you are using by yourself first. If you are having trouble with this, you can always ask for quick help in one of the [SO Chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign). Understanding your code is always better than simply copying functions.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You so much for saving a lot of time and effort on my end.